# (C) What i missed this code?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I don't know what I missed, I wrote the code using pointer to pointer code for exercise.

The code displays:

> num1 : 1
>
> num2 : 2
>
> num1 : 2
>
> num2 : 3
>
> num1 : 3
>
> num2 : 1636705

I guessed, last result maybe address at `_result[1]`, but I don't know why it's display, let me help to display last `num2` equals 4

```
#include <stdio.h>

void def_1(int num1, int num2, int *_return[2]);
void def_2(int num, int num2, int* _return[2] ,int **ptr[2]);
void main() 
{
   int num1 = 1;
   int num2 = 2;
   int* _return[2];
   int** ptr[2] = { NULL };

   printf("num1 : %d\nnum2 : %d\n", num1, num2);
   def_1(num1, num2, _return);

   printf("num1 : %d\nnum2 : %d\n", *_return[0], *_return[1]);
   def_2(num1, num2, _return, ptr);

   printf("num1 : %d\nnum2 : %d\n", **ptr[0], **ptr[1]);
}

void def_1(int num1, int num2, int* _return[2]) 
{
   _return[0] = &num1;
   _return[1] = &num2;

   *_return[0] += 1;
   *_return[1] += 1;
}

void def_2(int num1, int num2, int* _return[2] ,int** ptr[2]) 
{
   ptr[0] = &_return[0];
   ptr[1] = &_return[1];

   **ptr[0] += 1;
   **ptr[1] += 1;
}
```

Comment: Is this [tag:c] or [tag:c++] it's not the same, the answer below does not work in [tag:c],

Comment: `void main()` is wrong in both languages. In C, use `int main(void)`. In C++, use `int main()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are references to temporaries:

```
void def_1(int num1, int num2, int* _return[2]) 
{
   _return[0] = &num1;
   _return[1] = &num2;
}
```

Accept the `int`s by reference (C++)

```
void def_1(int& num1, int& num2, int* _return[2]) 
{
   _return[0] = &num1;
   _return[1] = &num2;
}
```

Or by pointer (C):

```
void def_1(int* num1, int* num2, int* _return[2]) 
{
   _return[0] = num1;
   _return[1] = num2;
}
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/DZxS6X)

Comment: The code looks like [tag:c], despite the [tag:c++] tag, it seems that the OP doesn't know there is a difference.

Comment: Thanks. Both tags were on the post. I edited this answer to account for both

Comment: Yes there are many important differences, in this case a very important one, there is no pass by reference in [tag:c],

Comment: @KIM: Ultimately, luck. Accessing the address of a variable that has gone out of scope is undefined behavior.